# Data frame manoeuvre

Tags: r, categorical-data, dataset

Suppose I have the following dataframe:

```
     Categories  Variable   
1        a          11
2        b          21
3        c          34
4        d          45
5        e          52
6        f          65
7        g          76
8        a          13 
9        b          24
```

I'd like to turn it into a new dataframe like the following:

```
     Categories  Variable   
1        a          11
2        b          21
3        c          34
4        d+e        97
5        f          65
6        g          76
7        a          13 
8        b          24
```

How can I do it? (Surely, the dataframe is much larger, but I want the sum of all categories of d and e and group it into a new category, say 'H').

Many thanks!

Answer (score 4):

This is a good question but unfortunately OT here. So I'll answer until it get migrated.
I'm assuming `Variable` is of class `factor`, so you'll need to properly re-level it (assuming your data is called `df`)

```
levels(df$Categories)[levels(df$Categories) %in% c("d", "e")] <- "h"
```

Next, I'll use the `data.table` package as you have a large data set and it's devel version (v >= 1.9.5) has a convinient function called `rleid` (download from [GitHub](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation))

```
library(data.table) ## v >= 1.9.5
setDT(df)[, .(Variable = sum(Variable)), by = .(indx = rleid(Categories), Categories)]
#    indx Categories Variable
# 1:    1          a       11
# 2:    2          b       21
# 3:    3          c       34
# 4:    4          h       97
# 5:    5          f       65
# 6:    6          g       76
# 7:    7          a       13
# 8:    8          b       24
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
# plyr package provides rbind.fill() function for row binding
library(plyr)

# Assuming you have a rows.cvs containing the data, read it into a data frame
data<-read.csv("rows.csv",stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

# Find the lowest index of d or e (whichever comes first)
index<-min(match("d",data$Var1.nominal.), match("e",data$Var1.nominal.))

# Returns all rows containing d and e in Var1(nominal) column
tempData<-data[data$Var1.nominal. %in% c("d","e"),]

# Remove all the rows containing d and e from original data frame
data<-data[!data$Var1.nominal. %in% c("d","e"),]

# Reorder row index numbers in data 
rownames(data)<-NULL

# Combine rows containing d and e in Var1(nominal)column, and sum up the column Var2(numeric)
tempData<-data.frame(Var1.nominal.="d+e",Var2.numeric.=sum(tempData[,2]))

# Combine original data and tempData frame with use of index 
data<-rbind.fill(data[1:(index-1),],tempData,data[index:length(data[,1]),])

# Renaming "d+e" to"h"
data[index,1]="h"

# Getting rid of the tempData data frame
rm(tempData)

Output:
> data
  Var1.nominal. Var2.numeric.
1             a            11
2             b            21 
3             c            34
4             h            97
5             f            65
6             g            76
7             a            13
8             b            24
```